# How to make variable accessible in the appDelegate and/or other view controllers?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, global-variables

I have a boolean variable that I need to access in my appDelegate, but I can't figure out how to do so. I have tried to import the other view controller and then implement it, but it comes up with an Apple Mach-O linker (id) error that says "Linker command failed with an exit code 1". I am fairly new to app dev, so please explain it in simple terms.  I am using storyboards, so I can't combine xib/nib files with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yon can declare a property in your MyAppDelegate.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *myString;
```

Then you can access it in your ViewController:

```
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"
...
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSLog(@"%@", appDelegate.myString);
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I wanted. I'll just change the string depending on what the state of the bool is.

Comment: You can declare `BOOL` property like this: `@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL  myBoolProperty;`

Answer (score 0):

**To access a Bool varible declare in AppDelegate.h to any other UIViewController..**

**1) in AppDelegate.h**

```
@property (nonatomic)BOOL myBool;
```

**2) in AppDelegate.m**

```
@synthesize myBool;
```

**3) to access myBool variable in any other UIViewController**

```
#define myAppDelegate [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]

// define above line below @implementation XyzViewController

 if (((AppDelegate *)myAppDelegate).myBool)
 {
    //implement logic    
 }
 else
 {

 }
```