# accessing an view controller ivar from appdelegate

Tags: appdelegate, ivar

I create a connection using NSURLConnection in my view controller class.  I want to make sure that my connections are nil when the AppDelegate calls the applicationWillResignActive methods.

I don't know how to call on that ivar from the AppDelegate.  There is an answer on this site:

[How to make variable accessible in the appDelegate and/or other view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200105/how-to-make-variable-accessible-in-the-appdelegate-and-or-other-view-controllers)

This could work, but is there another way?

Thanks

Comment: There are lots of ways to make objects communicate.  What's wrong with the one in the question you linked to?

Comment: nothing wrong with it - but wanted to know other ways for learning purposes...